# Update MySQL table column from another table entities

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables and I need to update a column from table2 using a column in table1. table2.id2 is empty and I must fill it using table1.id. Also, you must know that I have 2 columns that can be matched with each other in these tables (`table1.code` and `table2.code`).This is my SQL :

```
UPDATE table2 SET table2.id2 = table1.id WHERE table2.code = table1.code;
```

Is this query right ? I'm getting this error, while I'm sure that `table1.code` exists.

> [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'table1.code' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can join both tables using code

```
UPDATE T2
  JOIN T1 ON T1.CODE = T2.CODE
SET
  T2.ID2 = T1.ID
WHERE
  T2.ID2 = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work that way.

Take this:

```
UPDATE table2 SET id2 = (SELECT id from table1 WHERE code = 'somecode') WHERE code = 'somecode';
```

Comment: I don't know what is `somecode` in table records. I must do it for about 200 records with different values as `somecode`. Maybe I need a loop for it, but I'm not sure. Also I'm weak in writing loops in MySQL